# how to post json data to webservice

Tags: objective-c, json, web-services

i do have a json string that contains some attributes.

the json which look like this:

```
2013-06-26 14:59:06.363 DesignTable[1772:c07] {
  "Table" : {
    "Table name" : "F",
    "Number of Seats" : "4",
    "tableLocation" : {
      "y coordinate" : "141.00",
      "x coordinate" : "347.50"
    }
  }
}
2013-06-26 14:59:06.363 DesignTable[1772:c07] {
  "Table" : {
    "Table name" : "G",
    "Number of Seats" : "4",
    "tableLocation" : {
      "y coordinate" : "255.50",
      "x coordinate" : "360.50"
    }
  }
}
```

how to i post this to webservice and post it up to database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ASIHTTP for that like..

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.tag = 666;
    request.delegate = self;
    request.timeOutSeconds = 200;
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];


    [request setPostValue:@"YourData" forKey:@"your_key"];

    [request startAsynchronous];
```

may this help you....

Comment: Try this and If you have any problem in this, Post some piece of your code, i will explain this for your json.

Comment: i faced some error.. its say that "use of undeclared identifier 'BASE_URL'
"use of undeclared identifier 'request'"
"use of undeclared identifier 'ASIFormDataRequest'"

Comment: where do i declare those stuff? :)

Comment: base url is the url of your webservice.

Comment: hi nirav, sorry i encountered this error "NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ASIFormDataRequest initWithURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81b1e00" when i used ASIHTTP. any guide? thanks pal!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not just talking about json but about rest in general, then have a look at RestKit: http://restkit.org/
There is a nice tutorial here: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial